# Segmentation violation when trying to access vector entry

Tags: c++, vector, root

I've created a class, say I named it `MyClass`, as well as another that inherits from it, say `MyClassDaughter` then I tried the following:

```
MyClassDaughter *MyClassDaughterPointer;
vector <MyClass*> MyClassVector;
MyClassVector.push_back(MyClassDaughterPointer);
MyClassVector[0]->SetSomethingInMyClassDaughter;
```

When I try to run the executable it says "Segmentation Violation". 
(I think must say that my code has some Root stuff in it... Could that be the problem? Anyways, I know that, usually, segmentation violation errors are cause by trying to access memory that we don't have permission to access, but I think I do have permission to access this memory. Am I wrong?)

Answer (score 2):

You do not initialize MyClassDaughterPointer, so you push some random (wild) pointer to the vector.

You need to create new instance of MyClassDaughterPointer. Assuming you have a default constructor, it will look like this:

```
MyClassDaughter *MyClassDaughterPointer = new MyClassDaughterPointer();
```

Comment: The pointer value is *not* necessarily NULL - it can be anything.

Comment: Humm... This might be a dumb question (and I do feel dumb asking it) but how do I initialize it? MyClassDaughter *MyClassDaughterPointer= new MyClassDaughter (something something)??

Comment: @user2949903 I have provided an example. You either need to allocate new object or grab the address of existing one. Just make sure that its lifespan exceeds the lifespan of the vector in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer

```
MyClassDaughter *MyClassDaughterPointer;
```

Was never set to anything but there is some uninitialized content if that was on the stack or just null is that was static. Therefore you cannot try to access it as you do, that causes Undefined Behavior.

```
MyClassVector[0]->SetSomethingInMyClassDaughter; // that is same pointer set in vector entry
```

Unsure what compiler does as long as it usually has such code to be optimized out and that should not have any effect - no job for CPU here at all as long as that pointer is not used. But debug mode is right always attempting to load the address to some register.